# What code changes must be made to handle DCOM hardening? (CVE-2021-26414) (KB5004442)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dcom, network-security, hardening

Our clients are having issues with DCOM errors and the issues appear related to the so-called ["DCOM hardening" (CVE-2021-26414](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-26414)) ([KB5004442](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c)).  So we need to change our DCOM server processes and DCOM client processes so that they work now and they work on March 14th 2023 (the scheduled "no ability to disable them" date).

I am not sure what changes need to be made.  I *think* that the only required change is to add a call to `CoInitializeSecurity` after the call to `CoInitializeEx`, in both the server and the client.

```
HRESULT hrCoInit = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

/* Note: CoInitializeSecurity returns RPC_E_TOO_LATE
** instead of S_OK if it is called more than once.
** But we don't always know if this call is the
** first call to CoInitializeSecurity,
** so we ignore the return value. */

HRESULT hrCoInitSecure = CoInitializeSecurity(
    nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
    nullptr, EOAC_NONE, nullptr);
```

Could someone confirm this?  If not, I would appreciate it if you could tell me which "Co" functions should be called.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, both client and server can call CoInitializeSecurity and use RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/943138/what-code-changes-must-be-made-to-handle-dcom-hard-1.html